# pxssh don't want to return original command

Tags: python, pexpect, pxssh

I am using pxssh to run commands on the server, however the code I have prints the command I am running to a wx.multiline box; however I don't want to print the command I am running only the response.

Is there a way to only print out the output of the command using pxssh?

```
def runCmd(self, command):
    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login("127.0.0.1", "root", sshPass)
        s.sendline(command)
        s.prompt()
        stdout = s.before
        s.logout()
        return stdout
    except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
        self.progressBox.AppendText(str(e))
```

I'm assuming this is functionality built into the pxssh code for sendline/prompt, but is there a way to override printing the command on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe no one knew an official pxssh answer to this.

The way round I found was to split the output into lines, and then only print the output of the line that you want.

This removes all the other stuff including the command:

```
for line in stdout.split("\n"):
        if "DONE:" in line:
            print line
```